# How to fit a multivariable time series in Keras to another one?

Tags: time-series, classification, keras, lstm

I have a multivariable time series sensor data. I want to train a LSTM using Keras, 14 variables are sensor data of floats, and 16 variables are binary signals representing states liker alarms. My goal is that the neural network predict the alarms one or N time steps before by looking the sensor data. 
My data is in following way:
x_train.shape (1100, 14)
y_train.shape (1100, 15) #shifted by one for predict.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(14, input_dim=14, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(14, activation='relu'))
model.add(LSTM(14, activation='relu'))
```

I have the following error after first LSTM : ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_5: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

The last part of the code is this:

```
model.add(Dense(15, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=100, epochs=50)
```

Comment: You need to feed to LSTM layer an input of shape `(batch_size,timestep,nb_features)`. If you have 14 features and use one timestep, `x_train.shape = (1100,1,14)`